# Citing and Compiling BibTeX into Separate Documents

Tags: compilation, latex, bibtex, bibliography

I have an article document in LaTeX in which I cite sources from a bibtex file.  I want to be able to still cite these sources, but I also want to be able to compile the bibliography into a separate pdf document.  This document is a grant proposal for NSF, and they want the bibliography to be in a separate document.

I have searched the web for solutions to this problem.  Each solution is slightly different than what I need for my particular problem.

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bibentry}

...

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyBibliography}
```

The sources are included at the end of the document, and they are labeled "References".  I need them in a separate document, labeled "Bibliography".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main file is called `test`, you can simply import its bibliography in a new file with `\input{test.bbl}` and change the `\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}` or `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}`, depending on the documentclass. This way the references will have the same numbering as in the original document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}

\begin{document}

\input{test.bbl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm wondering, (1) how can I change the bibliography style that appears in the new file?  (2) how can I cite in the main file `test` without the bibliography appearing at the end of the file?

Comment: @user1723196 If you don't want a bibliography in the main file, add one anyway, change the name with `\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}` and the split the pdf in two, for example with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79626/36296